# Can't update iPhone 5S to the last iOS version (Verifying update)

Tags: software-update, iphone, ios

I am trying to install the latest iOS version (iOS 10.3.1) on my iPhone 5S. I've already downloaded it, I just need to install it. However, when tapping on "Install Now", it keeps saying "verifying update...", and so I cannot proceed further (I need to brutally reset my phone).

Can somebody help me fixing this issue?

Comment: For how long have you been trying? The problem may not be at your end, so trying again later often works. Also, have you tried rebooting your phone?

Comment: I have been having issues for longer than two weeks, but I finally solved the problem my updating via iTunes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restore is sometimes needed from iTunes when an over the air (OTA) update fails you repeatedly. iTunes restores have a couple of other advantages in addition to being far more reliable:

- chance to back up locally instead of iCloud
- less free space needed on the device (you don't need space to stage the upgrade and contain a download all on the device - just space needed to apply the change)